# How to convert 14.8V from Li-Po to 5V without producing heat?

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, lipo

I have a `14.8V` Li-Po battery and I want to stepdown the power to `5V 3A` as efficiently as possible without producing much heat. Which converter should I use?

Battery details are given below

```
{'Volt': 14.8, 'mAh': 6500, 'C': 100, 'S': 4, 'Amp': 650.0, 'Wh': 96.2}
```

Comment: What topologies have you looked at? Have you seen TIs Webench Power Designer website?

Comment: Will there be long periods of time when the battery voltage is connected to the converter but the 5V output current is zero? If so, the quiescent current specification of the converter might be just as important as the efficiency. Because the quiescent current of the converter is an ever-present load on the battery. For example a 5 mA quiescent current will drain a 2 Ah battery pack completely in 400 hours (17 days).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A buck converter should work, make sure you also provide for undervoltage protection or use a BMS (if lipo cells get too low in voltage they can be damaged). Also make sure the input of the Buck can handle the full range that the battery will supply ~17 to 12v

You won't be able to go entirely without heat, as switching regulators have some loss, but some switching regulators can get better than 95%.

Answer (score 3):

A DC/DC switching converter.  They make lots of them in 3-SIP packages that are designed to be drop-in replacements for 7805s.  1 and 1.5-amp outputs are very common; efficiency is 90%+.  Without knowing more about your requirements (inrush current, max ripple, protective features, etc), that's the best recommendation I can give.  I'm assuming your battery has built-in protection circuitry?